# Weird line appearing out of nowhere?

Tags: html, css, ruby, sinatra

I have a strange and small black, horizontal line appearing between my list items on my web app. I've create it using HTML, CSS, ruby, and sinatra. I'm not sure where they are coming from, and have looked at the dev tools, but have still not been able to find anything.

Picture: [image]

HTML/Ruby:

```
 `<h2>All Contacts</h2>


<% num = @@rolodex.counter %>
<% if num == 1 then number = "contact" %>
<% else number = "contacts" %>
<% end %>

<h2>You have <%= "#{@@rolodex.counter} #{number}" %>.</h2>

<ul class="contacts-list">
    <% @@rolodex.contacts.each do |contact| %>
        <a href="/contacts/<%= contact.id %>" class="hover">
            <li class="contactcards"> 
            <%= contact.first_name %> <%= contact.last_name %> <hr> 
            <%= contact.email %> <br> 
            Note: <%= contact.note %> <br> 
            ID: <%= contact.id %>
            </li>
        </a>
    <% end %>
</ul>`
```

CSS:

```
.contactcards {
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 24%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: slategray;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .7;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white
```

All contact list does is text-align center.

It should also be noted that the line is only visible when more than one contacts are present on the page (aka after a new contact has been entered into the rolodex). I have no idea where that line is coming from. Any help on this would really be appreciated.

Comment: post html & css or jsfiddle

Comment: I edited the post to include all HTML on relevant page. The only relevant CSS is the bit that I've posted

Comment: As a follow up, the line disappears when the link is removed from the HTML. I don't know why this is. Any reason why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine `<ul>` specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul-content-model):

> **Permitted contents**
>
> Zero or more `li` elements.

This may look like HTML:

```
<ul>
  <a>
    <li>...</li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

but it isn't. The only thing that can be a direct descendent of a `<ul>` is an `<li>` so the structure **must** be:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>...</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When a browser sees invalid "HTML", it will often attempt to correct it to match the specs before it is rendered. This correction process is probably introducing extra `<li>` and `<ul>` elements and that's probably where the mysterious black lines come from.

Comment: That explains why removing the anchor removed the line. Thanks for this. It messes with the formatting a bit, but the line is removed.